# How can I differentiate between an App Registration and Enterprise Application in Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I'm wondering if there is a way to tell whether a given application retrieved via command `Get-MgApplication` is an App Registration or an Enterprise App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-MgApplication` is the [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.applications/get-mgapplication?view=graph-powershell-beta) for **App Registrations**

`Get-MgServicePrincipal` is the [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.graph.applications/get-mgserviceprincipal?view=graph-powershell-beta) for **Enterprise Applications**

Microsoft generally refers to **App Registrations** as `applications/application objects`, and refers to **Enterprise Applications** as `service principals/service principal objects`. This is reflected in the cmdlet naming

See [Application and service principal objects in Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/app-objects-and-service-principals)